# How to add an admin alert for missing plugins

Tags: plugins, theme-development, admin

I'm trying to add an admin alert that reminds the user to install a certain plugin in case it is missing.  I have found a way to generally add an alert box:

```
function addAlert() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery;
$j().ready(function(){
$j('.wrap > h2').parent().prev().after('<div class="update-nag">This is a test alert. Do with it what you want.</div>');
});
</script>
<?php } add_action('admin_head','addAlert');
```

How do I only make it appear if the plugin is missing? I was thinking about something in the lines of `<?php if ( function_exists('...') ) ?>` but I am not too sure.

I also need a way of adding a link to the plugin and a link to dismiss the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a plugin is installed and activated, use the [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) function.

Note that you need to include this function first on the front-end before you can use it:

```
include_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
```

Avoid `function_exists()` for doing the check. Plugins may refactor their code and a previously existing function might disappear. You never know.

Comment: Tried this, but I keep getting the following error: `Call to undefined function is_plugin_active()` What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to include it first on the front-end. I'll update my answer.